# How to check if a word has a specific alphabet

Tags: javascript

Afetr string is splited by '/', it goes into 'includes' method.
A condition of includes has 'head'.
And even though the str has 'big head' , it has the word ' head'
If it is matched on this condition, I want to get 'true'.
How can it solve this problem?
Thank you so much for reading this.

```
const str = "big head/smallmouse/car";
const strSplited = str.split("/");
const condition = ['head','hand','foot']

console.log(condition.includes(strSplited[0]));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.some()` to iterate over each of the strings you want to test with `.includes()`.

```js
const str = 'big head';
const conditions = ['head', 'hand', 'foot'];
    
console.log(conditions.some(condition => str.includes(condition)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by revising your logic to search the `condition` array for an item `value` that is included in the `"big head"` (ie `strSplited[0]`) string.

In code that would look like this:

```js
const str = "big head/smallmouse/car";
const strSplited = str.split("/");
const condition = ['head','hand','foot']

const [ bigHeadString ] = strSplited;    
const result = condition.some(value => bigHeadString.includes(value));

console.log(`condition array contains match of ${strSplited[0]}:`, result);
```